# Using apply function Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, math, apply

I need help correcting an error I am getting.

I have the following dataframe:

```
x = [-0.75853, -0.75853, -0.75853, -0.75852]
y = [-0.63435, -0.63434, -0.63435, -0.63436]
z = [-0.10488, -0.10490, -0.10492, -0.10495]
w = [-0.10597, -0.10597, -0.10597, -0.10596]

df = pd.DataFrame([x, y, z, w], columns=['x', 'y', 'z', 'w'])
```

I created the following functions:

```
import math
def roll(qw, qx, qy, qz):
    # x-axis rotation
    sinr_cosp = +2.0 * (qw * qx + qy + qz)
    cosr_cosp = +1.0 - 2.0 * (qx * qx + qy * qy)
    roll = math.atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp)
    return roll

def pitch(qw, qx, qy, qz):
    # y-axis rotation
    sinp = +2.0 * (qw * qy - qz * qx)
    if(math.fabs(sinp) >= 1):
        pitch = copysign(M_PI/2, sinp)
    else:
        pitch = math.asin(sinp)
    return sinp

def yaw(qw, qx, qy, qz):
    # z-axis rotation
    siny_cosp = +2.0 * (qw * qz + qx * qy)
    cosy_cosp = +1.0 - 2.0 * (qy * qy + qz * qz)
    yaw = math.atan2(siny_cosp, cosy_cosp)
    return yaw
```

Finally, using Pandas apply function, I tried to associate the result with a new column:

```
q_w = df['w']
q_x = df['x']
q_y = df['y']
q_z = df['z']

df['row'] = df.apply(roll(q_w, q_x, q_y, q_z))
```

The same error occurs when using the other functions.

I saw an issue right here on Stack where this bug was fixed using Numpy. I believe this is not possible here because I am using functions specific to the Math package.

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last) /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
>   wrapper(self)
>        92         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
>   ---> 93                         "{0}".format(str(converter)))
>        94
>
> TypeError: cannot convert the series to
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last) 4 frames  in ()
>   ----> 1 df['row'] = df.apply(roll(q_w, q_x, q_y, q_z))
>
> in roll(qw, qx, qy, qz)
>         4     sinr_cosp = +2.0 * (qw * qx + qy + qz)
>         5     cosr_cosp = +1.0 - 2.0 * (qx * qx + qy * qy)
>   ----> 6     roll = math.atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp)
>         7     return roll
>         8
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
>   wrapper(self)
>        88 
>        89     def wrapper(self):
>   ---> 90         if len(self) == 1:
>        91             return converter(self.iloc[0])
>        92         raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to "
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py in
>   **len**(self)
>       593         Return the length of the Series.
>       594         """
>   --> 595         return len(self._data)
>       596 
>       597     def view(self, dtype=None):
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in **len**(self)
>       290 
>       291     def **len**(self):
>   --> 292         return len(self.items)
>       293 
>       294     def **unicode**(self):
>
> SystemError: PyEval_EvalFrameEx returned a result with an error set

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should using `apply` like

```
df.apply(lambda x : roll(x['w'],x['x'],x['y'],x['z']),1)
Out[291]: 
0   -2.175472
1   -1.909103
2   -0.394163
3   -0.397885
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also modify your function.

```
def roll(df):
    # x-axis rotation
    sinr_cosp = +2.0 * (df.w * df.x + df.y + df.z)
    cosr_cosp = +1.0 - 2.0 * (df.x * df.x + df.y * df.y)
    roll = math.atan2(sinr_cosp, cosr_cosp)
    return roll

df.apply(roll, axis=1)
```

Out:

```
0   -2.175472
1   -1.909103
2   -0.394163
3   -0.397885
dtype: float64
```